# Sorting a list of lists based on a list of strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

If I have a list:

```
arr = ['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
```

and a list of lists like that:

```
stats = [['a', 35, 109], ['b', 100, 50], ['c', 30, 80], ['d', 40, 50]]
```

I would like to order "stats" according to "arr". So, I want:

```
stats = [['b', 100, 50], ['d', 40, 50], ['a', 35, 109], ['c', 30, 80]]
```

Is there an easy way to do that in Python?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a key function which sort the nested list based on the index of first element in `arr` :

```
>>> arr = ['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
>>> stats = [['a', 35, 109], ['b', 100, 50], ['c', 30, 80], ['d', 40, 50]]
>>> sorted(stats,key=lambda x:arr.index(x[0]))
[['b', 100, 50], ['d', 40, 50], ['a', 35, 109], ['c', 30, 80]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` + `index` which is probably slow, or dictionary lookups which are probably fast:

```
arr = ['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
stats = [['a', 35, 109], ['b', 100, 50], ['c', 30, 80], ['d', 40, 50]]
# create dictionary by sort key
stats_dict = {x[0]: x for x in stats}
# use dictionary lookups to sort
sorted_arr = [stats_dict[item] for item in arr]
```

**Note:** this assumes a single item per letter, since they're used as keys in the dictionary.